# php - How to Prevent Word Breaks in Capitalized Acronyms in a String

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have word like following:

```
$string1 = ucwords("bookingID");
substr(preg_replace("/([A-Z])/", ',\\1', $string1), 1))
```

output is coming like : `Booking I D`

but I want to avoid space insertion if two consecutive capitals are there.

Expected output: `booking ID`

If I enter word like bookingAmountReceived then expected output is: `Booking Amount Received`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$String = 'bookingAmountReceived';
$Words = preg_replace('/[A-Z][a-z]+/', ' $0 ', ucfirst($String));
echo $Words;
```

Comment: Actually issue is different. If I given like bookingID then I want booking ID . I do not want space in between two consecutive capitals

Comment: @Aarti Borole , i have edited my code and make some change now hope it will work for you.

Comment: @Aarti Borole , welcome always.. i m happy to help someone if i can.

Comment: @devang :- but if string is like bookingIDDate, then this logic is creating Booking IDDate, while Booking ID Date is desired. Can you change the code to handle this scenario as well?

Comment: @Sujit Singh , ok i will change.

Comment: @Sujit Singh , now check my edited code , it will according to your scenario.

Comment: @devang : this works !! i must say, u r simply awesome !! great work.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a quantifier:

```
preg_replace("/[A-Z]+/", ",$0", $string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/[A-Z]+/", " $0", $string1);
```